# Fonts are not rendered properly

Tags: html, css, fonts, styles

I have a little experience with css, and learning it day by day, but I need to figure this out.

I have a little problem with defining the styles for the page.

My page contains the following sections:

```
<head>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:Light' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
.
.
.
.
<article>
            <header>
                <h1 class="txtName">Your pathway to success starts here</h1>
            </header>

            <p class="txtDesc">
               SomeText.................SomeText
            </p>
</article>
```

and I have the `.css` file containing the following section:

```
article h1
{
    color: #0140be;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: Light;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;   
}

article p.txtDesc
{
    line-height:1.6;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;          
}
```

The text inside the header is displayed with correct styles, however, text inside the paragraph is not displayed correctly. Looks like it is not recognizing given styles.
It displays the right `font-family`, but does not recognize `font-weight`.

What am I doing wrong here? Need some help.

Thank you

Comment: Font weight 400 and normal are the same thing, so even if you had included the correct font weights (per @IbrahimAlkan's answer), you would not have seen any difference between them. Instead of using `font-style: Light`, use `font-weight: 300`

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work. My text in the header became a little thicker. Wnen I define `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` in my <head> tag of my page, the header shows the correct styles, however, paragraph still does not have the correct styles. Basically, looks like, paragraph is taking the styles used by header. If I remove 300 from googlefonts definition, text in the header becomes thicker and paragraph displays correct styles.

Comment: Your `link` tag should look like `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`. You need both the 400 and the 300.

Comment: You could see this thread about fonts not rendering properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692151/fonts-are-not-rendered-correctly-in-release-mode-but-is-working-on-debug-mode-i?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `link` tag should look like

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

You need to include each of the font weights that you want in the URL.

Your styles should be:

```
article h1
{
    color: #0140be;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;   
}

article p.txtDesc
{
    line-height:1.6;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;          
}
```

You select which font style you want with the `font-weight` attribute.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zz8eqeL/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Link : https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans

As you can see there is styles for fonts like "Light 300 Italic" or "Extra-Bold 800". You must select that styles for bolder or lighter fonts. Then you can use font-weight in css otherwise it doesnt works.
Dont Forget: When you select "light 300" you can use font-weight:300. So font-weight:200 is not make any differences. If you select too much font styles it will take more time to load fonts from google when opening your page. You can see performance indicator on right.